# React / node : A request works from Postman but returns 400 from my front

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I created the backend of my application and I tested it with postman, it works. When I do a POST request with postman on "localhost: 5000 / api / user / login", I get the expected response.

But when i try from the front with axios i always get a 400 error which i can't seem to resolve, i did everything i could before asking the question here. I checked CORS, the payload, async await / then ... I'm stuck. If anyone can help me ... thanks.

My login function in backend :

```
module.exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Aucun compte n'est rattaché à cette adresse mail" });
  }

  // Compare the req.body.password to the hashed password in DB
  const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (match) {
    const maxAge = 1 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // day * (hour * minute * second * millisecond)
    try {
      //  Convert user id (ObjectId) to a string
      const userId = user._id.toHexString();

      // Assign a token
      const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.LOGIN_TOKEN, {
        expiresIn: maxAge,
      });
      res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge, sameSite: true });
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: `${userId}: Token assigned for ${maxAge} milliseconds` });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Mot de passe incorrect" });
  }
};
```

My front end who send the post request :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SignInForm = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
     const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/user/login`,
        data: {
          email,
          password
        },
      });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("catch : " + err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="sign-up-form">
      <label htmlFor="email">Adresse email</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        id="email"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setEmail(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={email}
      />
      <div className="email error"></div>
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="password">Mot de passe</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        id="password"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPassword(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={password}
      />
      <div className="password error"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Connexion" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

The response in my console.log :

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/user/login 400 (Bad Request)
react_devtools_backend.js:4049 catch : Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

The payload contains the expected data.

Comment: check cors settings

Comment: i have  set app.use(cors()), which must allow request from every where, but i have still the same error

Comment: dump your email and password in backend and check whether the pyaload is being received i suspect your password is undefined at the time its being compared to the encrypted one in DB

Comment: I did it, and finally I realized that I had this error because the user did not exist in the database. When I try to login an existing user, I receive the expected data. But when I enter the data of a user who does not exist, I just get a 400 error while via postman I get I defined message in the backend. i dont understand

Comment: maybe in postman you forgot to change your payload body .

Comment: I will check... but thanks anyway !